# SQL Server : Have a delayed version of the data

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

We have a SQL Server 2008 R2 Enterprise  a database that is populated with realtime data coming from multiple sources.

We want to have this data available as is in an internal application. However we would like to let this same data be accessed through another application (web) but in a "delayed" way.

Meaning that this application would only "see" the data as it was 5-10 or 15 minutes in the past.

Is there some out of the box way to do that? If not how would you suggest tackling that problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there is anything "out-of-the-box" to solve this.

The only thing I can think of is to add a datetime column to each table that should be accessed by the "other" application. That datetime needs to record the creation timestamp of the row.

Then create a view for each table that restricts the rows being returned based on the current time and the creation timestamp.

The "other" app is then only allowed access through the views.

Answer (score 1):

You can clone the database every 15 minutes and let the other app use the clone. Just backup the original database and restore it with diffrent name. This way you do not need to modify the data model at all. Just make sure you create a new database first and then let the web app use it. Never overwrite the database when its in use.

Comment: Yes, but at the exact moment of the clone, won't both database have the same state? 

So a client of the clone database accessing it at that moment will have the real-time data. We don't want that.

Comment: And we want "exactly 15 minutes in the past" difference. That way, the time difference will progressively change until the 15 minutes mark.

Comment: In fact, i think its impossible to achieve without changing data model and/or the software. The datetime column solution is a good way to go.